# fetch function returning CORS error while fetching a php page

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, cors, fetch

I am doing a ReactJs app that is using the function fetch in this way :

I have on my server a .php page that is printing a random quote and I want to fetch this quote from my React App that is hosted on the same server. But it's happening weirdly, I'll explain :

1) from my computer : `let newText = await fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.MYURL.com/actionv/API/aov_API.php");` will work as expected,
if I remove the `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` part it won't work (don't know why)

2) the same exactly app from the server that I built using `npm run build` won't work at all even if I use the `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` part...

"won't work" means I get this error :

> (index):1 Access to fetch at
>   'http://www.MYURL.com/actionv/API/aov_API.php' (redirected from
>   'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.MYURL.com/actionv/API/aov_API.php') from origin 'http://www.MYURL.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>       App.js:8 GET http://www.MYURL.com/actionv/API/aov_API.php net::ERR_FAILED
>       asyncToGenerator.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

the full function :

```
function App(){
  async function updateQuote(type){
    let newText = await fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.MYURL.com/actionv/API/aov_API.php");
    let msg = await newText.text();
    console.log(msg);
    setQuoteText(JSON.stringify(msg));
  }
```

Comment: " it wont work (don't know why..)" ....well did you go ahead and study what [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is? Then you might have some idea why, and also a better idea how to fix it (or at least have a better idea what else to research in order to try and fix it). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control might help you too

Comment: Also, you didn't tell us precisely what error you got. So I'm assuming it's a general CORS error but it would be far better if you told us precisely what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your answer can you tell me how I can give you a more precise error ? thats all i got in the browser..

Comment: Sorry silly me, I missed your error because you included it like code instead of a quotation. hang on I'll edit the question to format it more in the expected way

Comment: Anyway as the error says, there's a missing header in your response from PHP. Did you research CORS, or even google the error message? Then you'd know what CORS is and what it means. Which gives you a much better chance of fixing it. There is a lot of info available already. Read the two links in my first comment, and that should give you an overview of the technology, and then a sample PHP implementation.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control) I found that you need to add at the top of your .php file this :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

it allows fetching from the same origin

(Thanks to ADyson for the link)

Please if somebody thinks it's a security issue, tell me ! thanks